# Error when I click on any values of the keyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uisearchbar

Hi any kind souls out there,

I keep getting this error when i am click any value on the keyboard... I can run my codes but get this error when i want to do a search...

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM rangeOfString:options:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e2a830'
*** Call stack at first throw:
```

Please help this noob here.. I am at end wits... =(

```
- (void) searchTableView {

    NSString *searchText = searchBar.text;
    NSMutableArray *searchArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSDictionary *patients in listOfItems)
    {
         NSArray *array = [patients objectForKey:@"Patients"];
        [searchArray addObjectsFromArray:array];
    }

    for (NSString *sTemp in searchArray)
    {
        NSRange titleResultsRange = [sTemp rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        if (titleResultsRange.length != 0)
            [copyListOfItems addObject:sTemp];
    }

    [searchArray release];
    searchArray = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The objects in your search array are **NSArray** objects, this means that they do not respond to the selector **rangeOfString:** as that is a **NSString** method

```
for (NSString *sTemp in searchArray) 
{ 
   NSRange titleResultsRange = [sTemp rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
   if (titleResultsRange.length != 0)
     [copyListOfItems addObject:sTemp];
}
```

should be something like:

```
for(NSArray *array in searchArray)
{
   // NSString *str = [array objectAtIndex:0];
    PatientInfoObject *obj = [array objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *str = obj.id;
    // to be sure
    if( [str isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] )
    {
       NSRange titleResultsRange = [str rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveCompare];
       if( titleResultsRange.length != 0 )
       {
         [copyListOfItems addObject:str];
       }
    }
    else
    {
        // this shouldn't have happened, log something to console
        NSLog(@"**Object in array is not of type NSString**");
     }
}
```

Comment: thanks so much for your help... but I am getting the else part of the for loop everytime i press the keyboard.. what could the problem be?

thanks in advance.. =)

Comment: If you get to the else part it means that the object is still not a NSString, what objects are stored in that array? ( To figure that out dump the array to console using: NSLog(@"Array contents: %@",array); )

Comment: PatientInfo objects. They contain NSString ID, int category and int age. I hope to search using the ID... thats why i dun really understand your method since it does not only contains NSString objects...

=(

Comment: Then get the id of the PatientObject in your loop, see my edited answer above -- make sure that the NSString ID is set as a property so you can actually accesss it.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding array object in your searchArray.

your app is getting crash `NSString *sTemp in searchArray` here because sTemp contains NSArray object not NSString object.